# ClassicThesis B5 no margin at the bottom?

Tags: margins, classicthesis

I need to format my thesis in B5 format.
I use:

```
\documentclass[
twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,
                footinclude=false,cleardoublepage=empty,abstractoff,
                BCOR=5mm,b5paper,fontsize=12pt,
                spanish,american,
                ]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[b5paper,layout=b5paper]{geometry}
```

The resulting pdf is in B5 format, but I have no margins at the bottom and very little at the top. How can I fix that? Sorry, I no not have a lot of experience in latex and just copy-pasted the code from a friend.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you want to write your thesis in LaTeX, you need at least a basic understanding of how things work and not just copy-paste code. Each package has an associated documentation on the CTAN server where all options are documented. Just googling "CTAN geometry" gives you the documentation you need: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry . The options that control the margins are named `margin=<value>`, `hmargin=<value>`, `vmargin=<value>`. You can also directly specify margins directly via `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right`, `inner`, `outer`.

Comment: @Luke Do you have the latest version of classicthesis installed? No need to use `geometry` package. Footinclude=true, headinclude=true.

Comment: Where is the connection between `scrreprt` (used in the posted code)  and `classicthesis` (used in the tag and question title)?